# How to add individual plot labels to histograms in a multiple dataset layout?

Tags: graphics, labeling, histograms

How can I add individual labels to each histogram in a multiple dataset layout? See the following example:

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[3, 1], 500];

Histogram[{data1, data2}, ChartLayout -> "Row", 
 PlotLabel -> "Overall label"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ChartLayout`/`PlotLayout` mechanisms are not very flexible in my (limited) experience (Edit: See [@kglr's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283490/36508) for the built-in way to achieve this, if it works in your version). If you want more control, you'll have to use something else, such as [`ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/):

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][
 {{
   Histogram[data1, PlotLabel -> "Label 1", Frame -> True],
   Histogram[data2, PlotLabel -> "Label 2", Frame -> True]
   }},
 Spacings -> 
  5 (* add a gap between the plots to match the style of ChartLayout->"Row"*),
 "ShowFrameLabels" -> 
  Automatic (* hide frame labels despite the gap between plots *),
 PlotLabel -> "Overall label",
 PlotRange -> Max (* equalize the vertical plot ranges *)
 ]
```

[image]

You can just do all the styling on the individual plots themselves (plot labels, frame labels, colors, ...), and then combine them into a grid using `PlotGrid`, where you can then specify how stuff should be combined (hiding of frame labels, equalizing of plot ranges, gaps, sizes, ...). You could even combine different types of plots if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

```
Histogram[{data1, data2},
 ChartLayout -> "Row", 
 ChartLabels -> {{"dataset 1", "dataset 2"}, None}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Overall label"]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "13.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"
> ```

Comment: What version are you using? Because I tried something like this and for me, the labels are somehow overlapping the frame: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GVcq.png) (`13.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)`)

Comment: @LukasLang, i am using v3.1.0 on Linux.